# PayPal Adaptive Payment Library form to database output

Tags: arrays, database, paypal, payment

I have intensely searched for a solution to my paypal adaptive wish and I have found one, [PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php). However, it uses a form system (where the user puts in their own data and price), and that is not optimal for my system. Basically, people will upload an item and users can buy that item of a set item. The price will be fetched from the database in question and will be split by percentage, then the user would be sent to the paypal with right amount. I could use form and make the type hidden, but unfortunately that don't work either  because it's too insecure and I rather not expose all the data that can be changed.

The look of the form: http://i.gyazo.com/e6de8e40ccebbd6c7b381331983304b3.png

I wanted to convert the data array to something like the following, but the whole library was based on the [$i] function, which is an array function (?), but I don't know how to "convert" it to the one I want.

```
$Receivers = array();
$Receiver = array(
    'Amount' => '100.00', 
    'Email' => 'agb_b_1296836857_per@angelleye.com', 
    'InvoiceID' => '123-ABCDEF',  
    'PaymentType' => 'SERVICE', 
    'PaymentSubType' => '',  
    'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => ''), 
    'Primary' => 'true'                                                
    );
 array_push($Receivers,$Receiver);
```

[^taken from here](http://www.angelleye.com/demo/codeigniter/paypal/adaptive_payments/)

This is how it looks in the library of the payReceipt.php (where data gets processed and then sent to paypal, via numerous scripts that I can't honestly find..

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['receiverEmail']); $i++) {
    $receiver[$i] = new Receiver();
    $receiver[$i]->email = $_POST['receiverEmail'][$i];
    /*
     *      Amount to be credited to the receiver's account 
     */
    $receiver[$i]->amount = $_POST['receiverAmount'][$i];
    /*
     * Set to true to indicate a chained payment; only one receiver can be a primary receiver. Omit this field, or set it to false for simple and parallel payments. 
     */
    $receiver[$i]->primary = $_POST['primaryReceiver'][$i];

    /*
     * (Optional) The invoice number for the payment. This data in this field shows on the Transaction Details report. Maximum length: 127 characters 
     */
    if($_POST['invoiceId'][$i] != "") {
        $receiver[$i]->invoiceId = $_POST['invoiceId'][$i];
    }
```

Another example

```
if($_POST['paymentType'][$i] != "" && $_POST['paymentType'][$i] != DEFAULT_SELECT) {
        $receiver[$i]->paymentType = $_POST['paymentType'][$i];
    }
    /*
     *  (Optional) The transaction subtype for the payment.
     */
    if($_POST['paymentSubType'][$i] != "") {
        $receiver[$i]->paymentSubType = $_POST['paymentSubType'][$i];
    }
    if($_POST['phoneCountry'][$i] != "" && $_POST['phoneNumber'][$i]) {
        $receiver[$i]->phone = new PhoneNumberType($_POST['phoneCountry'][$i], $_POST['phoneNumber'][$i]);
        if($_POST['phoneExtn'][$i] != "") {
            $receiver[$i]->phone->extension = $_POST['phoneExtn'][$i];
        }
    }
}
$receiverList = new ReceiverList($receiver);
}
```

I'd be happy to send the library if you need to lurk inside there.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) instead.  It comes with samples that have static data in them, so you could update that easily with your own session data, database data, general PHP vars, or whatever you have the data stored in.

Comment: @andrew angell, yeah, I've downloaded it . Although, I keep getting error 50003 or something, basically no (or not right) api information, whilst it is!

Comment: In that case it sounds like you probably didn't $sandbox evaluating correctly in your config file, so it was sending sandbox credentials to the live server or vice-verse.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I believe I have set it, [link](http://pastebin.com/mSLfA08p) pastebin . Correct me if I'm wrong of course. One thing I do notice on my live server with this is this; "Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/a4897852/public_html/paypal-php-library-master/samples/Pay.php on line 23"

Comment: @AndrewAngell Worth noting is that I used the master one, because I couldn't get my head around how to install it with composer. Shouldn't have an effect should it?

Comment: You have it set, but it's evaluating to false the way you have it set.  Read through the comments above it and you'll understand what's happening there.  It may be easiest for you to just to set $sandbox = true on your own and remember to change it back to false when you go live.  Right now it's expecting you to be running from http://sandbox.domain.com, and only then would it set $sandbox to true.  You also need to update $domain in that config file, too.

Comment: @AndrewAngell alright, it works now, except when I get to finish page: http://i.gyazo.com/da7a43f4f79f7886f9f37964814ccb65.png . It seems as if it's only paying to ONE userhttp://i.gyazo.com/d25e7a2fd12d85a6751862c3bc04725c.png

Comment: I'd have to get a better look at the whole request.  If you want to [submit a ticket here](http://www.angelleye.com/support) I can work with you more directly.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Yaeh I figured it out. When you set something to primary and something else to false, it will ONLY take the primary one and pay that. Not sure if that's the purpose, I guess not? But it sort of defeats the purpose to have the primary receiver pay the fees, however I am in no need of that. 

-Also thanks for the help, the library of which you have created (didn't realize you were the creator, doh) has some really useful things in it. I presume there ain't no IPN in it, so will have to figure that part out somehow (heard it was complicated with paypal adaptive ipn specifically)

Comment: You must have something else going on there, because simply setting a primary receiver wouldn't cause that error you're getting.  One of the receivers must have a problem.  You might try different sandbox receivers or something.  Maybe one of them isn't verified..??  I don't have IPN built into the library itself, but there are plenty of good classes for that available on GitHub / Packagist.

Comment: @AndrewAngell  Don't know, it won't work when I use standard email either. But it's not a big concern, since that's fixed and all. Could you, ify you don't mind, possibly link a IPN for adaptive payments that works easily? I've tried few and tried to adapt IPNs for adaptive payments, without success. All I basically need is a ipn listener and to input the data in to a database. Would be much appreciated, because I'm having trouble finding a proper one.

Comment: The [one PayPal provides](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php) handles the data fine, but it's pretty bare bones.  If you happen to be using WordPress you could check out [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-ipn-wordpress/) or even just grab it to see how it's working.  It's quite a bit further along than a bare bones solution and supports all of the Adaptive Payments stuff.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I managed,  by taking bits and pieces from around the web, to make a script that gathers info from paypal (ipn), converts the data into a proper array (from raw data), that solves the issue with pay_key[i] etc. Then it just grabs info using paykey and I can then just add the data to database. Thanks for your assistance, your library is amazing and a huge asset.